# Proper way of bundling Native Modules with electron-builder?

Tags: node.js, module, electron, bundle, native

Is there a correct way of building native node.js modules that will properly bundle when packaging the application with electron-builder?

The correct way I ask for includes having the module be required properly in production, testing, and development.  Proper requirement in my eyes would be [`require('nativeModuleName')` instead of: `require('./build/Release/nativeModuleName')`], and not using file inclusion in the electron-builder sections of the 'package.json' file.